# Cannot assign a value of type 'NSObject?' to a value of type 'UIColor?'

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, uicolor

I am trying to set the background colour of cell to be equal to the UI colour in the dict, but I keep getting the error below. Even though when passing this as an array it works?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let colourList = [["Color" : "Red", "colourCode" : UIColor.redColor()],
                        ["Color" : "Yellow", "colourCode" :     UIColor.yellowColor()],
                        ["Color" : "Purple", "colourCode" : UIColor.purpleColor()],
                        ["Color" : "Green", "colourCode" : UIColor.greenColor()],
                        ["Color" : "Blue", "colourCode" : UIColor.blueColor()],
                        ["Color" : "Orange", "colourCode" : UIColor.orangeColor()]]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let dict = colourList[indexPath.row]
        print(dict) // e.g ["Colour": "Red", "colourCode": UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1] 
        print(dict["colourCode"]!) // e.g UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1
        cell.backgroundColor = dict["colourCode"] \\ ERROR - Cannot assign a value of type 'NSObject?' to a value of type 'UIColor?'

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.colourList.count
    }
}
```

Comment: try cell.backgroundColor = dict["colourCode"] as! UIColor

Comment: @Shoaib you should probably add this as an answer because that should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use as! to explicitly tell it's type

```
cell.backgroundColor = dict["colourCode"] as! UIColor
```

Answer (score 0):

make the following changes in the function.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //Reusing the cell
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier") as? UITableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CellIdentifier")
    }  

        let dict = colourList[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
        print(dict) \\ e.g ["Colour": "Red", "colourCode": UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1] 
        print(dict["colourCode"]!) \\ e.g UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1
        cell!.backgroundColor = dict["colourCode"] as! UIColor \\ ERROR - Cannot assign a value of type 'NSObject?' to a value of type 'UIColor?'

        return cell!
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily force a cast there

```
cell.backgroundColor = dict["colourCode"] as! UIColor
```

However, the problem is caused by bad design - you are mixing two types of data in one dictionary. Instead, you could use a helper class/struct:

```
class MyColor {
    let name: String
    let color: UIColor

    init(name: String, withColor color: UIColor) {
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
    }
}
```

used as

```
let colorList = [MyColor(name: "Red", withColor: UIColor.redColor()), ...]
```

than you can call directly (and without casting)

```
let myColor = colorList[indexPath.row]
cell.backgroundColor = myColor.color
```

Dictionaries are a poor's man replacement for objects.

Comment: Why would you pick a class over a struct here?

Comment: @donnywals Hmm, you could use a struct, too. There is no difference in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let colour = colourList[indexPath.row]["colourCode"] as! UIColor
    cell.backgroundColor = colour

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Consider adding some detail here.